# andorid ViewGroup childs isn't resized after onMeasure

Tags: android, kotlin, custom-view

I want to create my own ViewGroup with `ImageView` and some other views. I do this as follows (i have removed adding of other views for simplyfing the example):

```
class TestWidget @JvmOverloads constructor(
  context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

  init {
    addViews()
  }      

  private fun addViews() {
    val backgroundView = ImageView(context)
    backgroundView.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.kitten)) // image is 640x640 px
    addView(backgroundView)

    val text = TextView(context)
    text.text = "My awesome cat"
    text.textSize = 10.dp.toFloat()
    text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)

    addView(text)

    text.layoutParams = LayoutParams(
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ).apply {
      rightToRight = id
      leftToLeft = id
      topToTop = id
      bottomToBottom = id
    }
  }
}
```

I put this widget into xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <com.test.TestWidget
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The result is perfect (cat with text in the center):

[image]

Now i want to make my TestWidget always square. For that i am override `onMeasure` as follows (for portrait layout):

```
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
  super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
  setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredWidth)
}
```

And after that my cat becomes broken:

[image]

As you can see, my widget's height becomes equal to its width, but the `ImageView` is not redrawn, and is cut off. `TextView` is not redrawn too and is situated not in the center of my widget. I want to remove that empty space above the `ImageView`.

I tried to fix this behaviour with different ways: setting layout params to backgroundView with constraint, call `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` from `onSizeChanged()` callback, but nothing helps. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `onMeasure` like this way:

```
override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec)
}
```

Comment: thnx, it works, but as i said, besides ImageView I have others view (among them there are some custom views), which doesn't have smth like scaleType

Comment: @borune plz add example of code with adding other views

Comment: i have updated the code sample